# inferencing working with xquery but not sparql query

Tags: xquery, sparql, marklogic, inference

I am trying to run an example of inferencing using subClassOf relationship.

For some reason, I am getting the select query results when I use xquery but not when I use sparql.

### xquery

```
let $sq := 
'PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT *
WHERE { ?s rdf:type <http://www.smartlogic.com/geography#Europe> . 

} '

let $rs := sem:ruleset-store("rdfs.rules", sem:store())  

return sem:sparql($sq, (), (), $rs)
```

### sparql

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT *
WHERE { ?s rdf:type <http://www.smartlogic.com/geography#Europe> . 
}
```

Comment: The triples I am using are:    

<http://www.smartlogic.com/document#Credit_Suisse> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.smartlogic.com/geo#London> .

<http://www.smartlogic.com/geo#London> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://www.smartlogic.com/geo#Europe> .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now (MarkLogic 8.0-3), the SPARQL interface does not provide a way to specify a set of inference rules to use. [You can configure a default ruleset to use with the database](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/inferencing#id_pgfId-919120), which will be used with all SPARQL queries.

As you've done, you can use [sem:ruleset-store() (XQuery)](http://docs.marklogic.com/sem:ruleset-store) or [sem.rulesetStore() (JavaScript)](http://docs.marklogic.com/sem.rulesetStore) to specify a ruleset to use.